# Does tracking the loss via lists affect the training?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I wanted to plot the loss of my CNN, so created lists before starting to train with
`test_loss_history = [] train_loss_history = []` and added the values after every epoch with `train_loss_history.append(train_loss) test_loss_history.append(test_loss)`. I had done the same the same with the accuracy before, but when I add these lines for the loss, the accuracy drops around 40%. Does storing values affect the training process in any way?

I am using Google Colab and train a ResNet18 with a subset of MNIST.

My code looks like that:

```
    train_loss_history = []
    train_acc_history = []
   for epoch in range(epoch_resume, opt.max_epochs):
       ...
       for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
          train_loss     += imgs.size(0)*criterion(logits, labels).data
          ...
       train_loss     /= len(trainset)
       train_acc_history.append(train_acc)
       train_loss_history.append(train_loss)
```

Comment: Include the training part of the code. The provided information is not sufficient man.

Comment: I added a piece of code. If I delete everything related to train_loss_history then the accuracy gets higher. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Okay @chris, how do you calculate your accuracy ? Storing values wouldn't affect training process in anyway. Include that part of the code too.

Comment: since you used `.data` while storing, it won't affect. But, if you had stored directly, then it would have saved the reference to the loss tensor, and wouldn't have released the GPU memory in the next iteration and eventually you'll run out of memory. If you're not getting that kind of issue, I think you're doing it correctly. Personally, I use `.item()` on the loss if I want to store it (but I guess `.data` must have the same effect).

Comment: I compute the accuracy like that:    ` _, pred = torch.max(logits.data, -1)
  acc = float((pred==labels.data).sum())
  train_acc += acc `   . I also saw that     '.data'    is outdated so I'll try it with     'item()'   Do I have to add it so my accuracy list like that too?

Comment: So unfortunately using `.item()` instead of `.data` for the loss did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Tensorboard to plot loss and other metrics that you want to keep track of. Just you tensorboard default callback.

No need to saves metrics when tensorboard got your back

Comment: Thank you, after a few tries this worked! Although I still don't understand why using lists an `.item()` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
train_loss     += imgs.size(0)*criterion(logits, labels).data
```

I am assuming that `train_loss` is what you are backpropogating through (ie your code is calling `train_loss.backward()`. When saving the values in the list (for plotting later), use the `.item()` function. ie

```
train_loss_history.append(train_loss.item())
```

Most likely, you are storing the reference to the loss (and eventually you will run out of memory). Calling `.item` gives you the scalar value from the `loss` tensor and does not carry around the tensor.

Beyond your immediate question, you should not be using `.data` attribute. Are you on a very old version of PyTorch? (may 0.3 or lower)? If yes, you should consider upgrading.

You can find some more info on `.item()`, `.data` and upgrading PyTorch [here](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/#what-about-data). Its an old blog put it seems to apply to your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! So I tried it with `train_loss_history.append(train_loss.item()) `and also using tensorboard ([with this guide](https://medium.com/looka-engineering/how-to-use-tensorboard-with-pytorch-in-google-colab-1f76a938bc34)). But in every case the accuracy was lower than usually.

Comment: Right now I'm retrying with tensorboard and so far it doesn't look bad. Maybe this works and my first try was just bad luck.